# Inputs and Outputs of Pytorch's LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am working on training a LSTM model to predict the next few numbers in a sequence given the first few. I am trying to use PyTorch's LSTM model to do this, but I am unsure exactly what the inputs and outputs should be.

Let us say for the sake of argument that the given sequence is 6 numbers and I want to predict the next 3. I know that in the init function, I will give the model a nn.LSTM layer. However, I am unsure how to call this to get my next three numbers.

According to the documentation, it looks as if I am giving as input a tensor with dimensions (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size). For this example case, sequence_length is 6 and input_size is 10 (each given digit is actually the result of a previous prediction hence tensor of length is 10 for the probabilities of each digit).

Am I correct in assuming that these are my inputs?

According to the documentation, the result of an LSTM call is "output, (h_n, c_n)". output is a tensor of dimensions (batch_size, sequence_length, output_size). It seems that output_size = hidden_size, which I want to be 10 because I am predicting the probabilities of the next number being each digit.

This makes me believe that I am getting 6 predictions, one for each of the 6 inputs in the input sequence. However, I am unsure where I find the seventh number. Where do I find the model's prediction for the seventh number? Furthermore, once I have the seventh number, how do I find the eighth? Is the LSTM function capable of predicting as many numbers as I want it to, or do I have to do some kind of iteration, calling self.lstm each time, until I have as many numbers predicted as possible?

I recognize that some of the assumptions I have made may be wrong, so please correct any mistakes I made.

I was using this page for reference: [PyTorch LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html)

Comment: I think you can reference from this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405163/what-is-the-output-of-an-lstm